# Using Start-Job and ArgumentList How do you pass an array and string Values

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0

Using Start-Job and ArgumentList, how do you pass an array and another variable to the receiving script?

This works if I only need to pass a single array

```
Start-Job -FilePath "c:\thescript.ps1" -ArgumentList (,$newArray)
```

Tried this, but the second value is not being used in the receiving script.

```
Start-Job -FilePath "c:\thescript.ps1" -ArgumentList (,$newArray,"x")
```

thescript.ps1 example:

```
param (
    [string[]]$aMyArray,
    [string]$sMyString
)

function DoWork ([string]$aItem,[string]$sMyString)
{
    #worker
}

foreach($aItem in $aMyArray)
{
    DoWork $aItem $sMyString
}
```

I'm currently working in PowerShell 2.0

Comment: take the x out of the brackets. You don't use commas to delimit arguments. They are seen as a single object otherwise.

Comment: @Matt this is what you are suggesting?  -ArgumentList (,$newArray) "x"

Comment: Yes. It all depends on your use case and how thescript.ps1 is configured though.

Comment: @Briantist. He knows how to pass the array. Its the next arguments he is having an issue with. I was looking for a multiple arguments dupe but didnt find one i liked.

Comment: @Matt I see you're correct; reopened.

Comment: @Matt I've updated the post to include an example of thescrpit.ps1.  You see anything that would stop the second argument from being passed in?

Answer (score 2):

Just googled the same question but in the end I figured out. It's rather straight forward. Though in all posts the solution to pass an array to a job is (,$ArrayArg) and it works (for me it's still weird) if that is the only argument.
Though with multiple args, one being an array, this is what worked for me:

```
$foo1 = @("1","2","3")
$foo2 = "foo"

Start-Job -Name Test `
-ScriptBlock {
    param([string[]]$arg1,[string]$arg2)
    Write-Output $arg1
    Write-Output $arg1.GetType()
    Write-Output "----"
    Write-Output $arg2
    Write-Output $arg2.GetType()
} `
-ArgumentList @($foo1),$foo2
```

Comment: Yes, it's straight forward, but the provided examples didn't work.  In my case $aMyArray is a bunch of URLs.  Ended up going a different route.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I had to use something like `$using:foo1`.

Comment: It changes if you take away $arg2.

Comment: In fact, the @( ) doesn't do anything.  The ,$foo2 is what makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

I have to do it this way with the comma and parentheses around $list:

```
$list = echo a b c 

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  param ( $a )

  $a | % { $_ }
} -Args (,$list) | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Or with the `using` scope:

```
$list = echo a b c

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  $using:list | % { $_ }
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```